# Onclick isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So here I am wasting few hours on why isn't this thing working. I have a bigger function not working, so I decided to test this small one, yet it isn't working either. There are no errors, but nothing is happening after clicking the button.

```
<form>
            <input type="text" id="textField">
            <input id="filtrooo" type="submit" value="Click">
    </form>
<script>
        document.getElementById("filtrooo").onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById("textField").innerHTML ="txt";  
        };
</script>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: not every browser supports the onclick function directly. try to use `document.getElementById("filtrooo").addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('done'); });`

Comment: `textField` is an input field, use `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's woking now:

```js
<form>
    <input type="text" id="textField">
    <input id="filtrooo" type="button" value="Click">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("filtrooo").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("textField").value = "txt";  
    };
</script>
```

Instead of `innerHTML` you should write `value`. And another problem is that when you click submit button the page refreshes and the value of the input clears. So, instead of `type="submit"` here I use `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filtrooo = document.getElementById("filtrooo");

function functionName() {
    document.getElementById("textField").value ="txt";
}

filtrooo.addEventListener("click", functionName);
```

Comment: you are right, but your code has a failure ;) filterooo is undefined at the moment

Answer (score 0):

First, with a submit button, the page will be reloaded so you won't see what your code do.
Then, don't use `.innerHTML`. Use `.value` instead